# How to create build event in Visual studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

I want to create my own prebuild event to combine all javascripts files in visual studio.

Please suggest me how i can do this.

Please do not give links of available methods and dlls. I want to create my own dllss to do this.

Comment: What is your preferred build tool? Are looking to making a batch file to be executed in the prebuild event? Are you looking to make a custom MSBUILD task, or a custom NANT task? I usually prefer to have my build precompile the asp.net code first, and after it finishes i do all my merging/minizing of css and js files, than modify some config values to point to the new minimized files.

Comment: oh yeah, i just assumed you were using asp.net since it's visual studio. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The build events in Visual Studio basically lets you execute a list of command line statements before or after the build. So you should create your own exe files or batch scripts, and not dlls. (You can, of course, create a command line program that references some dlls.)

I other words:

- Create a command line program that you want to execute before you run the build command.
- Add the command in the Build Events tab on the Properties sheet for your project.